# Grunt serve watch error - Waiting…Warning error: watch ENOSPC

Tags: gruntjs

Running `grunt serve` on Linux creates an infinite loop:

```
$ grunt serve
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Warning: watch ENOSPC

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Warning: watch ENOSPC
...
```

Looking for suggestions to make it work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try with this command:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

It should works.

Comment: works perfect in Ubuntu 15.04 - 64bits

Comment: hi, what does this command do ?

Comment: Worked in Ubuntu 16.04 too!